# is there a way to limit the number of characters in textfields sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a table with

```
  username  TEXT  (20 characters) .....
```

Is this possible? I can use that limit only with `varchar` but I would like to use it with text, lontenxt

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `varchar()` with a length:

```
username varchar(20)
```

You use `text` specifically when you don't want to limit the length.

The more recent versions of MySQL also have check constraints.  So you can also use such a constraint:

```
constraint chk_t_username_length check (char_length(username) <= 20)
```

Comment: but what about limiting `longtext`?

Comment: @max . . . (1) That is not your question, because "text" <> "longext".  (2) For reasonable limits, use `varchar()`.  (3) A check constraint works on any such column.

Comment: longtext holds 4 gigabyte text strings. All of Shakespeare's writing is only about 6 meg. you want VARCHAR() not any kind of TEXT.